# cakephp 3 unable to sort by deeply associated data

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

We are not able to sort our transactions by deeply associated data. Mostly belongsTo and hasOne associations. Any information needed/not founded here will be posted immediately. Tables:

BcTransactions:

```
$this->belongsTo('Seller', [
    'className' => 'BcAccessCards',
    'foreignKey' => 'seller',
    'propertyName' => 'BcAccessCards',
]);
$this->belongsTo('Buyer', [
    'className' => 'BcUsers',
    'foreignKey' => 'buyer',
    'propertyName' => 'BcUsers',
]);
```

BcAccessCards:

```
$this->belongsTo('BcUsers', [
    'className' => 'BcUsers',
    'foreignKey' => 'user',
    'propertyName' => 'BcUsers'
]);
```

BcUsers:

```
$this->hasOne('BcUserInfos', [
    'className' => 'BcUserInfos',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'dependent' => true,
    'propertyName' => 'BcUserInfos'
]);
```

We are able to retrieve all the associated data for each transaction:

```
$query = $bcTransactions->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['BcTransactions.company =' => $id],
    'contain' => ['Seller', 'Seller.BcUsers', 'Seller.BcUsers.BcUserInfos', 'Buyer', 'Buyer.BcUserInfos'],
]);
```

Query returns perfect data set, but when it comes to sorting:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Seller', 'Seller.BcUsers', 'Seller.BcUsers.BcUserInfos', 'Buyer', 'Buyer.BcUserInfos'],
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id',
        'Buyer.BcUserInfos.firstname',
        'Seller.BcUsers.BcUserInfos.firstname',
    ]
];
$this->paginate($query);
```

We get following URL: `?sort=Seller.BcUsers.BcUserInfos.firstname&direction=asc` for example and we fail with an error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Seller.BcUsers' in 'order clause'` We understand what the error means, but dont know how to fix it, how to sort by deeply associated data.

Answer (score 0):

### Sorting works via identifiers

You seem to confuse this with how for example containments or filtering by associations works, where the "path" is required in order to retrieve association information at PHP level.

Sorting doesn't work that way, it happens purely on SQL level where the associated tables are joined in via their respective aliases. It eats identifiers, which consist of just an alias and a fieldname, so you'd just refer to fields of associations as for example `BcUserInfos.firstname` instead of `Seller.BcUsers.BcUserInfos.firstname`.

### Aliases must be unique when joined into a single query

Another problem you have there is that there are duplicate aliases, ie `BcUserInfos` is included twice, which won't work for `1:1` associations, as they are all being included in the same SQL query.

That will most likely cause problems as the query builder doesn't have a name conflict resolution that would include both associations, instead the one that was contained first will win, the following ones will simply not be included.

You'll probably have to rename them, add additional ones, or maybe even join the tables in manually.